# Truncate table in foreach breaking with table name 'order'

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to work with a script written by a previous developer that empties a number of different tables. The problem now is that I have added a table called 'order' and breaks the loop.

```
set_time_limit (0); 
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db('database-name');

$tables = array(
    'address',
    'manufacturer',
    'order',
    'voucher_history',
    'voucher_theme',
);

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $sql = sprintf('TRUNCATE TABLE %s', $table);
    printf('%s %s ', $sql, str_repeat('.', 73 - strlen($sql)));
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }else {
        echo "Done!<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a reserved keyword so it be must enclosed in back quotes:

```
'`order`',
```

Comment: can I add this into the sprintf()?

Comment: @John You mean `sprintf('TRUNCATE TABLE \`%s\`', $table)`? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

backquote your table names. Order is a reserved keyword and will cause your query to break

Comment: Better yet, don't name your tables using keywords.